# Needs to get Mobile device height exclude Keyboard whether it is open or close

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have `window.innerHeight` property in android mobile devices that changes when keyboard is open or closed. I want to get `height` of window whether keyboard is open or close.

Comment: try this document.documentElement.clientHeight

Comment: try window.screen.height

Comment: Thanks for your response But all these properties give small window height when keyboard is open. I face this issue in Android devices not in iOS. So please give me the way to calculate window height from screen.height because it is not effected with keyboard open.